# JQuery/Javascript works on & off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery 1.3.2-min in a project to handle JavaScript animations, ajax, etc. I have stored the file on the same server as the site instead of using Google. When I run the site locally on my development machine, everything works fine in FF, IE, Opera, and Safari (all the latest versions - I work from home and I only have 1 machine for personal use and development use) except for some CSS differences between them and when I go to the live site on my machine it works fine also. I have cleared my caches and hard refreshed the page, and it still works.

This is where it gets interesting however. When I send the site to my boss to test in various OS/Browser configurations, one page doesn't work correctly, some of it works, some doesn't. Also, the client (who uses IE 8) has also confirmed that it is not completely working - in fact he has told me that the page will work fine for a hour, and then just "turn off" for a while. I have never heard of this sort of thing before, and google isn't turning too much up. I have a hunch it may partly be with JQuery's .data(), but I'm not sure.

The page is basically nested unordered lists, and three basic actions happen on the list.
The top most unordered list is set to visible (all list via css are set to display: none to keep them hidden on a fresh page request); all list items divs are given a hover action of full opacity on mouseon, and faded back to 50% opacity on mouseoff; and then whenver a paragraph is clicked, the top most unordered list in that list item is displayed.

Here is my Javascript file for the page:

```
$(function() {
    // Set first level ul visible
    $('div#pageListing ul:first').css('display', 'block');

    // Disable all the hyperlinks in the list
    $('div#pageListing li a').click(function() {
        var obj;
        obj = $(this).parent(0).parent('div:first');
        highlight(obj); 
        return false;
    });

    // List Item mouse hovering
    $('#pageListing li').hover(
            // Mouse On
            function() {
                if ($(this).children('div').attr('id') !== 'activePage') {
                    $(this).children('div').css('opacity', 1).css('filter',
                            'alpha(opacity=100)');
                }
            }, // Mouse off
            function() {
                if ($(this).children('div').attr('id') !== 'activePage') {
                    $(this).children('div').css('opacity', 0.4).css('filter',
                            'alpha(opacity=40)');
                }
            });

    // Active list item highlighting
    $('#pageListing li div').click(function() {
            highlight($(this));
        });

    // Sub-list expanding/collapsing
    $('#pageListing p.subpageslink').click(function() {
        // Get next list
            var subTree = $(this).parent('div').next('ul');

            // If list is currently active, close it, else open it.
            if (subTree.data('active') != true) {
                subTree.data('active', true);
                subTree.show(400);
            } else {
                subTree.data('active', false);
                subTree.hide(400);
            }
        });

    // Double clicking of list item - edit a page
    $('#pageListing li div').dblclick(function() {
        var classes = $(this).attr('class');
        var classArray = classes.split(' ');
        var pageID = classArray[1];
        editPage(pageID);
    });

    // Handle button clicking
    $('button#addPage').click(function() {
        addPage();
    });

    $('button#editPage').click(function() {
        var div = $('div#activePage');
        var classes = div.attr('class');
        var classArray = classes.split(' ');
        var pageID = classArray[1];
        editPage(pageID);
    });

    $('button#delPage').click(function() {
        var div = $('div#activePage')
        var classes = div.attr('class');
        var classArray = classes.split(' ');
        var pageID = classArray[1];
        delPage(pageID);
    });
});

// Highlighting of page when clicked
function highlight(obj) {
    // Get previous hightlighted element
    // and un-highlight
    var oldElement = $('div#activePage');
    oldElement.css('background', 'white');
    oldElement.css('opacity', 0.4).css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=40)');
    oldElement.removeAttr('id');

    // highlight current selection
    obj.attr('id', 'activePage');
    obj.css('opacity', 1).css('filter', 'alpha(opacity=100)');
    obj.css('background', '#9dc0f4');

    // add appropiate action buttons
    $('button.pageButton').css('display', 'inline');
}

function addPage() {
    window.location = "index.php?rt=cms/editPage";
}

function delPage(page) {

    var confirm = window.confirm("Are you sure? Any sub-pages WILL BE deleted also.");

    if (confirm) {
        var url = './components/cms/controller/forms/deletePage.php';
        $.ajax( {
            url : url,
            type : 'GET',
            data : 'id=' + page,
            success : function(result) {
                if (!result) {
                    document.location = "index.php?rt=cms";
                } else {
                    window.alert('There was a problem deleting the page');
                }   
            }
        });
    }
}

function editPage(page) {
    var url = "index.php?rt=cms/editPage/" + page;
    window.location = url;
}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I find it worrisome that your delete page functions with a GET request.  Not only is that bad practice, but it actually violates the HTTP spec (http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet.html) I humbly ask you to switch it to POST only ;)

Comment: Agreed with Peter B., it's bad because it's too easy to inadvertently navigate to a URL and cause a potential catastrophic change on the backend, HTTP POST prevents this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the point - I was thinking of http traffic and didn't think of the possible URL problems.

Comment: Is it possible that the client's somehow switching IE8 out of standards mode and into quirks mode? I noticed that if I refresh often enough (or do a "hard" refresh to clear my cache) that it can jump. Might be worth a check: http://realtech.burningbird.net/standards/bobbing-heads-and-the-ie8-meta-tag/

Comment: That is possible and one of my thoughts. I have stepped the client though deleting his cache/history/etc in IE 8 and then refreshing the page, but the same problems appear.

I have gone through the source of the page, and fixed any XHTML 1.0 Strict error I found. Now I am waiting on a tester to try that possible fix and see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you one and all for your suggestions. The end problem was miscommunication. I work from home, and upload my projects to a SVN server, which the boss then uses to update the live server. Somehow, the correct files were not getting updated - a communication error on my part. Another possible reason was that the page, while being declared XHTML 1.0 Strict, had something like 50 validation errors (mosting incorrectly nested UL), and I cleaned that up to 5 errors. So thank you all, but again a sad example of the importance of team work communication.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are linking to (some of) the script files using a src that points to a file on your local disk/HDD? If so, that would explain why it works only on your machine, as then only your machine has access to the script file.

Comment: No,almost all of the links in the project (A self contained MVC framework) are relative to the file structure of the framework. Also, some of the functionality does work, and the working pieces also require JQuery, so I would assume it is getting loaded for those pieces to work.